# Anaconda 64bit install has begun to fail

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have been using Anaconda 3-5.0.1 with spyder3. Spyder has begun to fail.
I tried to remove and reinstall but reinstall fails. I removed hidden folder
anaconda3 to no avail. I now have no working spyder. I am installing 64-bit version in Windows 10. There are a variety of error messages including cant create menus. I have run this install many times prior to today (2/8/2018).
I assume continuum changed something.

I would greatly appreciate guidance.

Comment: Sure, you just need to do the thing

Comment: Seriously though, there is almost no useful information here. If you had a detailed description of the specific errors, including full text, that would be a start. "There are a variety of error messages including cant create menus" is basically a useless comment.

Comment: when install runs it says Anaconda3 5.0.1 (64-bit) Setup. At the failure point it was executing Execute: “C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\pythone.exe” –E –s “C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\L...

Comment: what runs is Anaconda3 5.0.1 (64-bit) Setup.

Comment: when install runs it says Anaconda3 5.0.1 (64-bit) Setup. At the failure point it was executing Execute: “C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\pythone.exe” –E –s “C:\Users\Stephen\Anaconda3\L... Error message is "Failed to create menus". If I say ignore error, it says completed, but there is no anaconda icon on desktop or entry in start menu.

Comment: Please do not put crucial information into comments. Use the edit button below the question. Don't forget to format console output as code.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who still have the same issue, try to follow the link below. 
http://shirabeta.net/Anaconda-install-error.html#.WopGl6huY2z
You may need to have a google translate as it's a Japanese blog.
I deleted JDK, JRE and all java related paths in the environment setting as suggested in the blog. Then I could successfully install anaconda3.5.1.0_64bit with no error.